# Creating a User (Transaction)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and I am working on the Sign-up method. It works ok out of the box, but now I need to add data to another tables on the register process.

Is there anyway to create users with ASP.NET identity using a Transaction? So that any data would be discarded on an error?

```
var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser()
{
    UserName = model.Email,
    Email = model.Email
};

// My application context here will add data to other tables
........

var createResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, model.Password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since ASP.NET Identity uses the data context that you provide you can just create [transaction through Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx). Just make sure it is the same instance of the data context.

Comment: So how can I access the identityDbContext ? Is it inside my UserManager? Can I get it from ``HttpContext`` ? Thanks

Comment: You can't get it from the HttpContext. Get it from the same place you used to put it in the UserManager. Normally this would be some kind of dependency injection container. If you are creating it yourself just store it somewhere so you can use it.